# Breaking Vigenere via Kasiski/Babbage method? (non-programmatic)

Tags: cryptanalysis, vigenere

I'm really hoping someone can explain to me what is going on in the second major component of this form of analysis.

If you wish, for convenience, here's a page that already has some ciphered text and a known codeword: http://www.martani.net/2011/04/cracking-vigenere.html

Anyhow, I think I understand how to get the keyword length just fine (shift same-text and highest collision is likely key length) with the factor+collision method.

However, once the step of dividing up the text comes about, I'm lost as to how to use it to obtain the key. I understand using frequency analysis, but thus far all I've managed on my own samples is a gibberish key...

If someone could explain this step of the decipherment in simple terms, I would be very grateful as I have a test on it this week and I know my instructor will try and throw this my way...